# Como pular uma linha inteira somente se o campo estiver vazio em PHP?

Tags: php, php-7

Estou gerando um script sql para um arquivo csv. Gostaria de gerar o arquivo sql somente onde o campo id não está vazio. se o campo estiver vazio que ele pule a linha e não gera aquela linha no meu script sql.

```
    <?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 */
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');

include 'utils.php';

// Filename contem o nome do CSV passado por parêmetro na linha de comando
$filename = (count($argv) > 3) ? $argv[3] : '';
// Lê o arquivo e o converte para um array com a lista de dados
$csv = parseCsv($filename);
// Extrai metadados do nome do
$path_parts = pathinfo($filename);

/**
 * Dicionário de colunas.
 * Cada item desse array deve conter a chave igual a coluna do cabeçalho do CSV
 * e no valor o nome da coluna no banco de dados.
 */
$dicionario_colunas = [
    'ID parâmetro' => 'ID',
    'Nome do Parâmetro' => 'NOME_PARAMETRO',
    'ID SKU' => 'ID_TR',
    'Nome do TR/SKU' => 'TR_NOME',
    'Unidade de medida que aparecem ao lado do resultado no laudo' => 'UNIDADE_RESULTADO',
    'Categorias de resultados em texto que podem estar no laudo' => 'CATEGORIA_RESULTADO',
    'Limite inferior de detecção' => 'LIMITE_INFERIOR',
    'Limite superior de detecção' => 'LIMITE_SUPERIOR',

];

$csv = normalizeCsvArrayKeys($csv, $dicionario_colunas);

if (empty($csv)) {//verificando se o seu file.csv está vazio
    die("Arquivo csv vazio\n");
}


$examesEquipamentos = [];
foreach ($csv as $linha) {
  $examesEquipamentosId = trim($linha['ID']) . '-' . trim($linha['ID_TR']);
    if (!array_key_exists($examesEquipamentosId, $examesEquipamentos) ) {
        $examesEquipamentos[$examesEquipamentosId] = [
            'ID' => trim($linha['ID']),
            'NOME_PARAMETRO' => trim($linha['NOME_PARAMETRO']),
            'ID_TR' => trim($linha['ID_TR']),
            'TR_NOME' => trim(mb_strtoupper($linha['TR_NOME'])),
            'UNIDADE_RESULTADO' => trim($linha['UNIDADE_RESULTADO']),
            'CATEGORIA_RESULTADO' => trim($linha['CATEGORIA_RESULTADO']),
            'LIMITE_INFERIOR' => trim($linha['LIMITE_INFERIOR']) ?:0,
            'LIMITE_SUPERIOR' => trim($linha['LIMITE_SUPERIOR']) ?: 0,
        ];
        //Para filtrar os id. se tiver vazio, não retornar isso na lista do script.se for contrário, dai retorna
       $examesEquipamentos[$examesEquipamentosId] = array_filter($examesEquipamentos[$examesEquipamentosId], function ($valor) {
            return trim($valor) !== '';
        });

    }
}

$migrationID = date('YmdHis');
$migrationRef = 'exames_tr_equipamentos';
$migrationName = $path_parts['filename'];
$outputName = $migrationID . '_' . $migrationRef . '_' . $migrationName . '.sql';
$output = fopen(ROOT . '/db_crx/migrations/' . $outputName, "w"); # not readedlines

try {
    echo "\nProcessando os dados\n";

    echo "Iniciando output.\n";

    fwrite($output, "SET search_path = \"rx_ref\";\n");
    fwrite($output, 'BEGIN;' . "\n\n");

    fwrite($output, "UPDATE exames_tr_equipamentos SET obsoleto = NOW();\n");

    if (!empty($examesEquipamentos)) {
        fwrite($output, "\n" . "-- insert / update exames_tr_equipamentos\n");
        foreach ($examesEquipamentos as $examesEqui) {
            $stmt = "INSERT INTO exames_tr_equipamentos (exame_id, tr_equipamento_id, unidade, categoria_resultado, limite_inferior,limite_superior) VALUES (" .
                "'{$examesEqui['ID']}','{$examesEqui['ID_TR']}', '{$examesEqui['UNIDADE_RESULTADO']}','{$examesEqui['CATEGORIA_RESULTADO']}',".
                "'{$examesEqui['LIMITE_INFERIOR']}','{$examesEqui['LIMITE_SUPERIOR']}') ".
                "ON CONFLICT (exame_id, tr_equipamento_id) DO UPDATE SET unidade = '{$examesEqui['UNIDADE_RESULTADO']}',".
                "categoria_resultado = '{$examesEqui['CATEGORIA_RESULTADO']}',limite_inferior = '{$examesEqui['LIMITE_INFERIOR']}', limite_superior = '{$examesEqui['LIMITE_SUPERIOR']}',".
                "obsoleto = null;\n";
            fwrite($output, $stmt);
        }
    }


    fwrite($output, "DELETE FROM exames_tr_equipamentos WHERE obsoleto IS NOT NULL;\n");

    fwrite($output, "\n" .
        "INSERT INTO public.crx_migrations (id, reference, description, filename) VALUES ('$migrationID', '$migrationRef', '$migrationName', '$outputName');\n");

    fwrite($output, "\nCOMMIT;\n");
    echo "Output pronto.\nVerifique o arquivo $outputName na pasta de migrações\n";

}
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "\n" . "Ocorreu uma exceção durante a geração do script:\n";
    echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
    echo $e->getTraceAsString() . "\n";

    if (file_exists($output)) {
        unlink($output);
    }
}
```

Comment: Acho que quebrou na hora que publicou o código, quando fez o comentário,

Comment: me explique certinho, como assim quebrou @ Bulfaitelo??

Comment: O código , coloca ele completo, e depois ou antes coloca sua observação

Comment: Arrumei ali. o trecho de código que eu tentei colocar foi:   //Para filtrar os id. se tiver vazio, não retornar isso na lista do script.se for contrário, dai retorna
       $examesEquipamentos[$examesEquipamentosId] = array_filter($examesEquipamentos[$examesEquipamentosId], function ($valor) {
            return trim($valor) !== '';
        });

Comment: Esses id vazios viriam do csv ? caso sim como eles viriam ? sendo um valor valido e não sendo valor valido.

Comment: @Bulfaitelo sim, vem do csv. quero simplesmente preencher meu sql sem a linha que possui um id vazio

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88801/discussion-between-bulfaitelo-and-gladiador).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adicionei a condição para que ele adicione, os valores na variável `$examesEquipamentos` quando, quando o valor da função[`strlen($linha['ID']);`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strlen.php) for maior que 0, isso é quer dizer que existe algum valor, ele ira inserir os valores no vetor;

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 */
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');

include 'utils.php';

// Filename contem o nome do CSV passado por parêmetro na linha de comando
$filename = (count($argv) > 3) ? $argv[3] : '';
// Lê o arquivo e o converte para um array com a lista de dados
$csv = parseCsv($filename);
// Extrai metadados do nome do
$path_parts = pathinfo($filename);

/**
 * Dicionário de colunas.
 * Cada item desse array deve conter a chave igual a coluna do cabeçalho do CSV
 * e no valor o nome da coluna no banco de dados.
 */
$dicionario_colunas = [
    'ID parâmetro' => 'ID',
    'Nome do Parâmetro' => 'NOME_PARAMETRO',
    'ID SKU' => 'ID_TR',
    'Nome do TR/SKU' => 'TR_NOME',
    'Unidade de medida que aparecem ao lado do resultado no laudo' => 'UNIDADE_RESULTADO',
    'Categorias de resultados em texto que podem estar no laudo' => 'CATEGORIA_RESULTADO',
    'Limite inferior de detecção' => 'LIMITE_INFERIOR',
    'Limite superior de detecção' => 'LIMITE_SUPERIOR',

];

$csv = normalizeCsvArrayKeys($csv, $dicionario_colunas);

if (empty($csv)) {//verificando se o seu file.csv está vazio
    die("Arquivo csv vazio\n");
}


$examesEquipamentos = [];
foreach ($csv as $linha) {
  $examesEquipamentosId = trim($linha['ID']) . '-' . trim($linha['ID_TR']);
    if (!array_key_exists($examesEquipamentosId, $examesEquipamentos) ) {
        if(strlen($linha['ID']) > 0){

            $examesEquipamentos[$examesEquipamentosId] = [
                'ID' => trim($linha['ID']),
                'NOME_PARAMETRO' => trim($linha['NOME_PARAMETRO']),
                'ID_TR' => trim($linha['ID_TR']),
                'TR_NOME' => trim(mb_strtoupper($linha['TR_NOME'])),
                'UNIDADE_RESULTADO' => trim($linha['UNIDADE_RESULTADO']),
                'CATEGORIA_RESULTADO' => trim($linha['CATEGORIA_RESULTADO']),
                'LIMITE_INFERIOR' => trim($linha['LIMITE_INFERIOR']) ?:0,
                'LIMITE_SUPERIOR' => trim($linha['LIMITE_SUPERIOR']) ?: 0,
            ];
        }
    }
}

$migrationID = date('YmdHis');
$migrationRef = 'exames_tr_equipamentos';
$migrationName = $path_parts['filename'];
$outputName = $migrationID . '_' . $migrationRef . '_' . $migrationName . '.sql';
$output = fopen(ROOT . '/db_crx/migrations/' . $outputName, "w"); # not readedlines

try {
    echo "\nProcessando os dados\n";

    echo "Iniciando output.\n";

    fwrite($output, "SET search_path = \"rx_ref\";\n");
    fwrite($output, 'BEGIN;' . "\n\n");

    fwrite($output, "UPDATE exames_tr_equipamentos SET obsoleto = NOW();\n");

    if (!empty($examesEquipamentos)) {
        fwrite($output, "\n" . "-- insert / update exames_tr_equipamentos\n");
        foreach ($examesEquipamentos as $examesEqui) {
            $stmt = "INSERT INTO exames_tr_equipamentos (exame_id, tr_equipamento_id, unidade, categoria_resultado, limite_inferior,limite_superior) VALUES (" .
                "'{$examesEqui['ID']}','{$examesEqui['ID_TR']}', '{$examesEqui['UNIDADE_RESULTADO']}','{$examesEqui['CATEGORIA_RESULTADO']}',".
                "'{$examesEqui['LIMITE_INFERIOR']}','{$examesEqui['LIMITE_SUPERIOR']}') ".
                "ON CONFLICT (exame_id, tr_equipamento_id) DO UPDATE SET unidade = '{$examesEqui['UNIDADE_RESULTADO']}',".
                "categoria_resultado = '{$examesEqui['CATEGORIA_RESULTADO']}',limite_inferior = '{$examesEqui['LIMITE_INFERIOR']}', limite_superior = '{$examesEqui['LIMITE_SUPERIOR']}',".
                "obsoleto = null;\n";
            fwrite($output, $stmt);
        }
    }


    fwrite($output, "DELETE FROM exames_tr_equipamentos WHERE obsoleto IS NOT NULL;\n");

    fwrite($output, "\n" .
        "INSERT INTO public.crx_migrations (id, reference, description, filename) VALUES ('$migrationID', '$migrationRef', '$migrationName', '$outputName');\n");

    fwrite($output, "\nCOMMIT;\n");
    echo "Output pronto.\nVerifique o arquivo $outputName na pasta de migrações\n";

}
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "\n" . "Ocorreu uma exceção durante a geração do script:\n";
    echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
    echo $e->getTraceAsString() . "\n";

    if (file_exists($output)) {
        unlink($output);
    }
}
```

Comment: cara vc ganhou meu respeito!! Duas vezes e acertou na mosca!! Muito obrigado por ter aceitado de me ajudar eu já estava ficando louco por aqui hahahaha